# How to stop word 'Array' from rendering in table HTML?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

> **How to stop the work 'Array' from being part of the output?? It appears between the headers and the data rows, and I can't get rid of it. Is my HTML wrong for dynamic table rendering?? I would embed a picture but I'm not allowed yet to do that**

```
UserID  First Name  Last Name   E-mail  Phone   Action
`Array`  
9   Lenny   Kravits ld@mail.com (234) 231-9999   
8   Sally   Simpson ss@gmail.com    (425) 455-5678   
7   Chad    Merit   chad@mail.com   4251119988   
6   Janet   Miller  janlmill@yahoo.com  4251119988   
5   Tom Smith   ts@mail.com (425) 826-3344   
4   James   Miller  jimomak@leader.com  (425) 471-8101   
3   Ron Weasly  ron@gmail.com   (111) 222-3344   
2   Harry   Potter  harry@gmail.com (789) 654-135    
1   Sahil   Kumar   sahil4rock@gmail.com    (078) 965-1235
```

> This is the getusers.php file that the Javasript calls as async/await/fetch.

```
<?php include_once 'init.php';
error_reporting(1);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("CALL getUsers()");
$stmt->execute();
do {
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();
} while ($stmt->nextRowset() && $stmt->columnCount());
foreach ($data as $row) {
$data .= '  
<tr>
<td>' . $row['userId'] . '</td>
<td>' . $row['fName'] . '</td>
<td>' . $row['lName'] . '</td>
<td>' . $row['email'] . '</td>
<td>' . $row['phone'] . '</td>
<td>
<a href="#" id="' . $row['userId'] . '" class="btn btn-success btn-sm                   
rounded-pill py-0 editLink" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs- 
target="#editUserModal">Edit</a>
<a href="#" id="' . $row['userId'] . '" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm 
rounded-pill py-0 deleteLink">Delete</a>
</td>
</tr>        
';
}     
echo $data;      
?>
```

> This is the user.php file with embedded Javascript in the same page (for now). This is the first time using the fetch api, with async/await. Everything renders, but the 'array' word appears as part of the 'response'...and I've never had this issue before? For clarity I'm called a mysql stored procedure, very simple select * query...it works fine and the data renders.Using 'document.querySelector("table")...maybe I have to dynamically render the whole table...which doesn't yet work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet">                
<link href="css/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<title>Comments</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row mt-4">
<div class="col-lg-12 d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
<div>
<h4 class="text-primary">All users in the database!</h4>
</div>
<div>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs- 
target="#addNewUserModal">Add New User</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
<div id="showAlert"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered text-center">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>UserID</th>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
<th>E-mail</th>
<th>Phone</th>
<th>Action</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<!--Filled by AJAX-->
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
const tbody = document.querySelector("tbody");
// Fetch All Users Ajax Request
const fetchAllUsers = async () => {
const data = await fetch("includes/getusers.php", {
method: "GET",
});
const response = await data.text();
tbody.innerHTML = response;
console.log(response);
};
fetchAllUsers();
</script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check your init.php for any echo or print.

Comment: Init.php is good...it only holds the pdo db connection object. Thank you though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you fetch all users:

> > $data = $stmt->fetchAll();

Then, you append your rows to it:

> > $data .=

Just create a new variable for your output and you're good to go.

Comment: I gave both of you the credit. You each had the same solution with more or less detail, but exactly the same answer. Thank you. This saved me lots of trial and error. I was so close, but so far away.

Answer (score 1):

You have reused a variable that is concatenating the `HTML` with the `Array object`

To Solve this, just rename the `HTML` variable to something like this:

```
<?php include_once 'init.php';
error_reporting(1);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("CALL getUsers()");
$stmt->execute();
do {
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();
} while ($stmt->nextRowset() && $stmt->columnCount());
foreach ($data as $row) {
$htmlData = '  
<tr>
<td>' . $row['userId'] . '</td>
<td>' . $row['fName'] . '</td>
<td>' . $row['lName'] . '</td>
<td>' . $row['email'] . '</td>
<td>' . $row['phone'] . '</td>
<td>
<a href="#" id="' . $row['userId'] . '" class="btn btn-success btn-sm                   
rounded-pill py-0 editLink" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs- 
target="#editUserModal">Edit</a>
<a href="#" id="' . $row['userId'] . '" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm 
rounded-pill py-0 deleteLink">Delete</a>
</td>
</tr>        
';
}     
echo $htmlData;      
?>
```

Comment: this worked perfectly...many thanks. I suffered from myopia...not the first or the last I'm sure. This helped a lot. Very gracious.